# Bootstrap NavBar do not set up li class="active" with React-Router. ReactJS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, navbar

I have a React-Component called `MenuAlumno` which is a Bootstrap NavBar. I am usign ES6 - ReactJS - React-Router.

This is my component:

```
render() {
    return (
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">

            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle navbar-collapse-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#idNavBarCollapsed" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Menú</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs-block" /*href="http://www.upct.es/"*/><span id="idTextoLogotipo">- INCIDENCIAS -</span></a>
            </div>

            <div id="idNavBarCollapsed" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li><Link to='/administrador/inicio'>Inicio</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to='/administrador/nueva_incidencia'>Nueva Incidencia</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to='/administrador/incidencias_recibidas'>Incidencias Recibidas</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to='/administrador/informes'>Informes</Link></li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="divider visible-xs-block"></li>
                    <p class="navbar-text navbar-text-center hidden-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Bienvenido, {this.state.nombre} ({this.state.dni})</p>
                    <p class="navbar-text navbar-text-center visible-xs-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Bienvenido, {this.state.nombre}</p>
                    <li class="navbar-text-center"><a href="http://www.upct.es/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Salir</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </nav>
    );
}
```

But when I click on a `<li>` it is not setted up as active. How could I resolve this? I have trying a lot of diferent thing but I do not achieve this yet....

Also, I want that if i am on a route which it is not defined on navbar (like: `/administrador/inicio/hi/How_are_you/Fine`) the corresponding `<li>` will set up as active (in this example: `/administrador/inicio`) but that if I have another element (defined on the NavBar) as: `/administrador/inicio/hi` this is not active (I say this through the window.location.pathname.include ('/administrador/inicio') -this will active both links-). Activate only the parent `<li>` (the `<li>` which throws me to that url), not the 'possible parents'.

Also, I want that when I click F5, it continues as active.

In this proyect I can not use React-Bootstrap, so this option is not possible.

I've been warming my head for a long time trying to solve this but I still have not got it. Any help is welcome.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:

```
render() {
    return (
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">

            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle navbar-collapse-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#idNavBarCollapsed" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Menú</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs-block" /*href="http://www.upct.es/"*/><span id="idTextoLogotipo">- INCIDENCIAS -</span></a>
            </div>

            <div id="idNavBarCollapsed" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li><NavLink to='/administrador/inicio'>Inicio</NavLink></li>
                    <li><NavLink to='/administrador/nueva_incidencia'>Nueva Incidencia</NavLink></li>
                    <li><NavLink to='/administrador/incidencias_recibidas'>Incidencias Recibidas</NavLink></li>
                    <li><NavLink to='/administrador/informes'>Informes</NavLink></li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="divider visible-xs-block"></li>
                    <p class="navbar-text navbar-text-center hidden-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Bienvenido, {this.state.nombre} ({this.state.dni})</p>
                    <p class="navbar-text navbar-text-center visible-xs-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Bienvenido, {this.state.nombre}</p>
                    <li class="navbar-text-center"><a href="http://www.upct.es/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Salir</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </nav>
    );
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this set it on the a element, when it should be on the li?

Answer (score 0):

I have previously run into this problem. you should attention something about 'this props' of route , you can find the route has changed[image] ,then you through this change to do something.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I do not know what I have to do with it.

Comment: I put: 
        console.log(this.props) but returns an empty object

Answer (score 0):

may be you are looking for this

```js
var selector = '.nav li';

$(selector).on('click', function(){
    $(selector).removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
li.active {
    color: Red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
    <li style="cursor:pointer">Inicio</li>
    <li style="cursor:pointer">Nueva Incidencia</li>
    <li style="cursor:pointer">Incidencias Recibidas</li>
    <li style="cursor:pointer"> Informes</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: More or less, but that gives problems when having to do a Reload with F5. With child routes that do not appear in NavBar or belong to the parent clicked also give problems.